# Sending complex form data to ajax calling ASP.NET page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, database

I have a form written below:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Worker Type:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="WorkerTypeTB"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Worker Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="WorkerNameTB1"/></td>
        <td>Worker Position</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="WorkerPositionTB1"/></td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Worker Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="WorkerNameTB2"/></td>
        <td>Worker Position</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="WorkerPositionTB2"/></td>        
    </tr>
    .
    .
    .
    <tr>
        <td>Worker Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="WorkerNameTBn"/></td>
        <td>Worker Position</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="WorkerPositionTBn"/></td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" id="SaveBTN"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It has one worker type field, and dynamically generated N (WorkerName,WorkerPosition) fields.

What is the best way to send data to AJAX calling ASP.NET page?

I am using following jQuery AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "AjaxMethod.aspx",
       data: data,
       //dataType: "json", ??????
       //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" ?????   
    });
```

Should I use JSON or some other dataType to send my data to ajax calling page? 
I would like to optimally format my form data in following manner:

```
workerType: developer
workers:
    workerName1: Jack
    workerPosition1: Johnson
    workerName2: Joe
    workerPosition2: Phillips
    ...
    workerNameN: Walter
    workerPositionN: Wolf
```

How to format this kind of data to JSON if JSON is best dataType to use for sending data to ajax calling page?
How to send this JSON object via jQuery AJAX?

How to accept this type of data on server side Page_Load function and how to read it's elements?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: BTW: don't use tables for layouts. See: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms

Comment: I know that it is not the best idea to use tables as layouts, but I've written it here just as a sample for my problems inserting form data in db via jQuery ajax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This article walks through using ASP.NET, JSON, [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js), and jQuery:

[Using complex types to make calling services less… complex](http://encosia.com/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/)

Comment: It's fascinating how good is this workaround. Thank you very much. Can you explain me what is in the background of translating JSON to .NET objects?

Comment: ASP.NET uses the JavaScriptSerializer automatically for serialization and deserilization.